# DOWN arrow and DELETE are suddenly mapped to toggle enable/disable touchpad

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I let some friends use my laptop (acer aspire s7) and when i got it back (they had no idea what they were doing) this had happened, what i've found so far:
1) down arrow disables touchpad
2) delete enables touchpad
3) up- and right arrow does not do anything

I have checked xev, and down arrow and delete does indeed say touchpadOn/Off.
I have ubuntu 14.04

I found my exact problem in an older thread but no response: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549182

Please help me!

Comment: I'm seeing this exact problem with Ubuntu 18.04. Sometimes restarting fixes it, sometimes not. I really wish I had a way to fix this without restarting.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried checking the "input" under system settings? I don't have it in front of me but I believe the tab "gestures and shortcuts" would solve your problem. Or just hit "restore default settings (on that tab, not the whole system)". Other than that you would have to find the folder and file for your keyboard mapping. Also check to see if they changed the keyboard layout in "input" as well.

[image: keyboard]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no "restore default settings"-option, but i googled and found unity-restore, a program to simulate unity --restore on older ubuntu versions. However this didn't change anything (EDIT: yes it did, but just not this thing). It seems like there must be some kind of key-combination that caused this since it really is EXACT the same keys doing the EXACT same thing as in the post i linked in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, You simply put Your keyboard ps2 plug into a mouse socket, just switch it to the right socket (purple one).